# How do I increase a static int number?

Tags: c#

I don't know how to increase `numberquestion` when they get the correct answer.
If you are able, please help me do so by telling me how to increase `numberquestion` by `1` everytime a correct answer is given so it knows when to move on to the next question.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

note: I'm using unity game engine^^^^^

```
public class TextControl : MonoBehaviour {

List<string> questions = new List<string>() {"When does time fly?","When does time?","When does?"};

List<string> CorrectAnswer = new List<string>() {"3","3","3"};

public static string SelectedAnswer;

public static string ChoiceSelected="n";

public static int numberquestion=0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = questions [numberquestion];
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (ChoiceSelected == "y") 
    {


        if (CorrectAnswer [numberquestion] == SelectedAnswer) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Correct");
            numberquestion++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is the end part `numberquestion++` that I need to change to make it increase by one.

Comment: The code is correct...

Comment: Looks like homework

Comment: And what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a non static variable to save the current count at the time of the instantiation. Give this a try:

```
public class TextControl : MonoBehaviour {

   List<string> questions = new List<string>() {"When does time fly?","When does time?","When does?"};

   List<string> CorrectAnswer = new List<string>() {"3","3","3"};

   public static string SelectedAnswer;

   public static string ChoiceSelected="n";

   public static int numberquestion=0;

   public int myNumberQuestion;

    // Use this for initialization
   void Start () {
   GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = questions [numberquestion];
   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update () 
   {
       if (ChoiceSelected == "y") 
   {


    if (CorrectAnswer [numberquestion] == SelectedAnswer) 
    {
        Debug.Log("Correct");
        myNumberQuestion = ++numberquestion;
        }
    }
}
```

}